# Чи правильно казати "розстрочка"?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, калька, віддієслівні-іменники

На всіх сайтах нерухомості чи продажу квартир зустрічається слово *розстрочка*

Чи можна вживати це слово, чи воно має якийсь аналог в українській мові?

[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozstrochka)

> *РОЗСТРО́ЧКА*, и, жін. Виплата або виконання чого-небудь частинами у визначені строки. — Скільки ж то він коштує? — Та щось тисяч до двох. І в розстрочку (Андрій Головко, I, 1957, 273); Зустрівся я на вулиці з паном Глянцером, у якого мені доводилося колись брати матеріали для костюма.. в розстрочку (Петро Козланюк, Сонце.., 1957, 122).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покупать в рассрочку — купляти на виплат.

Рассрочка — розклад(ання) виплат, розклад(ання) на рати/на терміни, розтермінування.

Все та більше [звідси](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Розстрочка — це не калька (буквально перекладене), а прямий росіянізм. Калькою радше є "розтермінування" ("роз" + "термін" замість рос. "срок").

Comment: А чому _розстрочка_ не калька — в українській мові же є слово _[строк](http://sum.in.ua/s/strok)_?

Comment: Тому що "розстрочення". "Розстрочка" складніша, я б не назвав її калькою вже принаймні через те, що остання морфема там російська. На фоні цього "т" видається декоративною, а не буквальним перекладом як у випадку "терміну". Тобто це пряме запозичення з подальшою асиміляцією згідно нашої вимови.